# Avoid allocation errors with destroy() and async functions

Tags: javascript, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

The following is a simple scenario for some GNOME extension:

1. Enable the extension. The extension is a class which extends
   `Clutter.Actor`.
2. It creates an actor called `myActor` and adds it:
   `this.add_child(myActor)`.
3. Then it calls an asynchronous
   time-consuming function `this._tcFunction()` which in the end does something
   with `myActor`.

Here's where I run into a problem:

1. We disable (run `this.destroy()`) the extension immediately after enabling it.
2. On disabling, `this.destroy()` runs GObject's `this.run_dispose()` to
       collect garbage. However, if `this._tcFunction()` has not finished running,
       it'll later try to access `myActor` which might have been already
       deallocated by `this.run_dispose()`.

One way to go about this, is to define a boolean variable in `this.destroy()`

```
destroy() {
    this._destroying = true
    // ...
    this.run_dispose;
}
```

and then add a check in `this._tcFunction()`, e.g.

```
async _tcFunction() {
    await this._timeConsumingStuff();

    if (this._destroying === true) { return; }

    myActor.show();

}
```

My question: is there a nicer way to deal with these situations? Maybe with `Gio.Cancellable()`? AFAIK, there's no easy way to stop an async function in javascript...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, two things to be aware of:

1. Avoid calling low-level memory management functions like `GObject.run_dispose()` as there are a cases in the C libraries where these objects are being cached for reuse and aren't *actually* being disposed when you think they are. There is also no dispose signal and other objects may need notification.
2. Avoid overriding functions that trigger disposal like `Clutter.Actor.destroy()` and instead use the destroy signal. GObject signal callback always get the emitting object as the first argument and it is safe to use *that* in a destroy callback.

There are a couple ways I could think of solving this, but it depends on the situation. If the async function is a GNOME library async function, it probably does have a cancellable argument:

```js
let cancellable = new Gio.Cancellable();

let actor = new Clutter.Actor();
actor.connect('destroy', () => cancellable.cancel());

Gio.File.new_for_path('foo.txt').load_contents_async(cancellable, (file, res) => {
    try {
        let result = file.load_contents_finish(res);

        // This shouldn't be necessary if the operation succeeds (I think)
        if (!cancellable.is_cancelled())
            log(actor.width);
    } catch (e) {
        // We know it's not safe
        if (e.matches(Gio.IOErrorEnum, Gio.IOErrorEnum.CANCELLED))
            log('it was cancelled');

        // Probably safe, but let's check
        else if (!cancellable.is_cancelled())
            log(actor.width);
    }
});

// The above function will begin but not finish before the
// cancellable is triggered
actor.destroy();
```

Of course, you can always use a cancellable with a Promise, or just a regular function/callback pattern:

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   // Some operation
   resolve();
}).then(result => {
    // Check the cancellable
    if (!cancellable.is_cancelled())
        log(actor.width);
});
```

Another option is to `null` out your reference, since you can safely check for that:

```js
let actor = new Clutter.Actor();
actor.connect('destroy', () => {
    actor = null;
});

if (actor !== null)
    log(actor.width);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice to avoid  using`run_dispose()`, I wasn't aware of that kind of caching.

As for error handling, I ended up using `if (e.matches(Gio.IOErrorEnum, Gio.IOErrorEnum.CANCELLED))` in functions that involved asynchronous calls. Problem solved.